# "SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'team'@'localhost' to database 'my database''

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, cpanel

I want upload my Laravel Project in Cpanel.

The first page is the login page for users that when a user logins, he is redirected to another page.

When I want to send the user information to the database, I get this error:

> "SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'team'@'localhost' to database 'my database'"

In `Cpanel` I'm creating a database and a user.

In `phpMyAdmin` I'm creating my tables.

Alson in `env` file I Add username and database name,

Where is my mistake? How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you correctly configure your database in Laravel? In `config/database.php` or in your `.env` file

Comment: No How I Can do this?

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/database#configuration

Answer (score 2):

Change your .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=user_name
DB_PASSWORD=user_password
```

Answer (score 1):

Fist check your `.env` file. Make sure you put the right credentials for the database name, username and password. The database name and username in cPanel ususally starts with your cPanel username, such as `cPanelUsername_databaseName`.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cpanelUsername_databaseName
DB_USERNAME=cpanelUsername_databaseUser
DB_PASSWORD=thePasswordYouSet
```

If that does not solve the problem, you might want to check if you have the user added to the database. You will find it in the `MySQL Database`. If not, then navigate to the `MySQL Database` section inside the cPanel and scroll down and you will find `Add User To Database` and then select the user that you want to give permission to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs mostly in the live server go to the panel then go to MySQL Databases and add user privilege to the database you want then put these user credentials in yours.env file