# Symfony - test database can not be created

Tags: database, symfony, environment-variables, symfony4

I am trying to create my test database within `Symfony 4.4` project using:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test
```

But keep getting an error:

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'myproject_user'@'%' to database 'myproject_test'
```

In my .env.test url is defined like:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://myproject_user:password_1@database:3306/myproject_test
```

What is causing the problem? I can assume it's `@` character, but this way is my database url defined in `.env` file also. I can not figure out what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your DATABASE_URL is correct.
The problem come from your user which exist, but has no acces right to create table in database.

You can see some existing post about this problem:

[SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'ion'@'localhost' to database 'a901ce392dad4b90b1c6e175b07196a9'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57981602/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1044-access-denied-for-user)

["SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'team'@'localhost' to database 'my database''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163218/sqlstate42000-1044-access-denied-for-user-teamlocalhost-to-database-m)

[ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db)